# How load $http service app on startup in Ionic framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

**How load $http service app on startup in Ionic framework?**

**// This is a service**

```
appModule.factory('NewGames', function($http, $ionicLoading) {
  // JSON Array

  var newGames = [];

  var request = {'searchString' : 'name_fr'};
  $http.get('http://example.com/rest/data.php', { cache: true}, request).success(function(response) {
      newGames = response;

  });


  return {
    all: function() {
      //$ionicLoading.hide(); 
      return newGames;

    }

  }
});
```

**// This is a controller**

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, NewGames, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $stateParams, $ionicPlatform) {


  $scope.nextSlide = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
  }

  $scope.newGames = NewGames.all();

});
```

**If you press the button, the data is loaded. How to make so that the data was loaded at startup?**

Comment: But add 

 var request = {'searchString' : 'name_fr'};
  $http.get('http://example.com/rest/data.php', { cache: true}, request).success(function(response) {
      newGames = response;

  }); 

in controller - apps load startup.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ionic.Platform.ready()` method, [documented here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/).

You can run this method from anywhere in your app, may it be factory or controller.